# One line conditional assignment if statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, for-in-loop

This is the first question I am asking on this forum, so I welcome your feedback on making this more helpful to others.

Say I have this list:

```
IDs = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
```

and this dictionary:

```
statistics = {('First', 'Name'):"FirstName", ('Second','Name'):"SecondName", ('Third','Name'):"ThirdName"}
```

Is there a shorter, easier to read one-liner than the following?

```
firstID = IDs[[statistics[ID,'Name'] for ID in IDs].index('FirstName')]
```

Many thanks

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Looks valid to me, as long as you read the rest of the line. Not very efficient design, though.

Comment: so unreadable I thought that it was incorrect!

Comment: Any particular reason you put your dict in this direction, instead of switching the keys and values? If you need lookups in both directions, have you considered making a second, reversed dict?

Comment: What do you wanna do? I do not understand your purpose..

Comment: Why is this happening?

Comment: Yeah, there is: `firstID = IDs[0]`

Comment: @Coldspeed maybe instead of firstID I should have put sampleID, because it won't always be the first element, I just did that for the sake of simplicity

Comment: @Mr_U4913 trying to look up ID by value from a dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient (and probably more readable) approach would be this:

```
firstID = next(id for id in IDs if statistics[(id,'Name')]=='FirstName')
```

This defines a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) which checks the `IDs` in order, and yields values from `statistics` that equal `"FirstName"`. [`next(...)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) is used to retrieve the first value from this iterator. If no matching name is found, this will raise `StopIteration`.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
# If you ever plan to change the order of IDs:
firstID = IDs[IDs.index('First')]

# If you are literally just looking for the first ID in IDs:
firstID = IDs[0]
```

If you look at your code in these two lines:

```
IDs = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
firstID = IDs[[statistics[ID,'Name'] for ID in IDs].index('FirstName')]
```

The index of `'FirstName'` in your newly created list will ALWAYS be equal to the index of `'First'` in `IDs`. Because your list comprehension will iterate `IDs` in order and put the corresponding `dict` values in that order, you will always create `'FirstName'` at the same index as `'First'` appears in `IDs`. Therefore it is far more efficient simply to call it from that list using one of the above methods.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking to search for the ID ('First') of an element just by using its name ('FirstName')